# Google reCAPTCHA v3 can't find any token

Tags: token, content-security-policy, invisible, recaptcha-v3

So it's the first time I'm trying to use the google reCAPTCHA v3 (actually it's the first time I'm using any kind of captcha).

I followed the documentation and a very basic tutorial. 
What I understand is that I should be able to see the token in my browser inspector.

The **first issue** is that i can see the logo on the bottom right of my screen, but there is definitely no token in my input.

The **second issue** comes from the browser console which indicates 3 kind of errors.

I'm working with `Symfony Framework` on a local environment.
Any clue would be much appreciated !

[My twig & javascript files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49se1.jpg)

[Browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mngjo.png)

[Content-Security-Policy issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbdOq.png)

Answer (score 2):

So i figured out how to get the token....

I just had to remove those lines in the js file:

```
function onclick(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
```

I still didn't find about the Content-Policy issues.